# no valid session found,must call init and login before logout

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I only have login via facebook in my ionic 2 app. I installed cordova pluginfor that with this code

```
`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"`
```

Sometimes I see this message pop up on my app:

> no valid session found,must call init and login before logout

and my app crashes. Below is a screenshot:

[image]

I have already tried to delete the app and install it again but the issue still persists.

this is my facebook login

```
Facebook.login(['email']).then( (response) => {
  let facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider
      .credential(response.authResponse.accessToken);
  var that = this;
  firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential)
      .then((success) => {
        that.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Firebase failure: " + JSON.stringify(error));
      });

}).catch((error) => { console.log(error) });
```

}

get details from facebook

```
//facebook functions


 getDetailsFacebook() {
    var that=this;
    Facebook.getLoginStatus().then((response)=> {
      if (response.status == 'connected') {
        Facebook.api('/' + response.authResponse.userID + '?fields=id,name,gender', []).then((response)=> {
          //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
         that.uid = response.id;
          that.name=response.name;
         that.photo = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+that.uid+"/picture?type=large";
          that.user=new User(that.uid,that.fireUid,that.name, that.photo);
          that.profileData.setProfileData(that.user); // to create class for that

          //that.profileData.setProfile(that.uid,that.name,that.photo);
          //console.log("id:"+this.uid+this.name+this.photo);
        }, (error)=> {
          alert(error);
        })
      }
      else {
        alert('Not Logged in');
      }
    })
```

log out function

```
     logOutFacebook(){
    Facebook.logout().then((response)=>
    {
      this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
      alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    },(error)=>{
      alert(error);
    })
  }
```

**home.html**

```
 <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="pinka">
    <ion-title></ion-title>
    <ion-buttons start (click)="addNote()">
      <button ion-button>
        <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
      </button>

    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding class="padiHome">
 <ion-avatar>
   <img src={{photo}}>
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>

 </ion-avatar>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let note of notes">
      <ion-item [ngStyle]="{'background-color':'note.color'}">

        <h2>{{note.title}}</h2>
        <p>{{note.desc}} +  {{note.color}}</p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item-options side="left" style="direction:ltr">
        <button ion-button="secondary" (click)="update(note.id)">
          <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>
         edit
        </button>
        <button ion-button="danger" (click)="delete(note.id)">
          <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
          delete
        </button>
      </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
<button ion-button (click)="logOutFacebook()">log Out</button>
</ion-content>
```

home.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController,NavParams,LoadingController,AlertController,ViewController  } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Facebook } from 'ionic-native';

//import pages
import {LoginPage} from "../../pages/login/login";
import {User} from '../../models/user'
import { Storage} from '@ionic/storage';
//import provider
import { ProfileData } from '../../providers/profile-data';
import { NotesData } from '../../providers/notes-data';

import firebase from 'firebase'
import {AddNote} from "../add-note/add-note";
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
  //facebook user
  userProfile: any = null;
  uid: any = null;
  fireUid:any=null;
  name:string=null;
  photo: any = null;
  user:User=null;
  photos:any=null;
currentUser:any=null;
  //notes list

  notes:any=null;
  data:any;



  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public profileData:ProfileData,private viewCtrl: ViewController,public notesData:NotesData,private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,private alertCtrl: AlertController,public storage:Storage) {
    this.data={};
    this.data.title="";
    this.data.desc="";

  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log("home");
    this.fireUid=firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    this.currentUser=firebase.auth().currentUser;
    this.storage.get('photo').then( (value:any) => {
     this.photo=value;
    });
    this.storage.get('name').then( (value:any) => {
      this.name=value;
    });

    //this.getDetailsFacebook();
    this.getNotesList();
  }

//facebook functions
  getDetailsFacebook() {
    var that=this;
    Facebook.getLoginStatus().then((response)=> {
      if (response.status == 'connected') {
        Facebook.api('/' + response.authResponse.userID + '?fields=id,name,gender', []).then((response)=> {
          //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
         that.uid = response.id;
          that.name=response.name;
         that.photo = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+that.uid+"/picture?type=large";
          that.user=new User(that.uid,that.fireUid,that.name, that.photo);
          that.profileData.setProfileData(that.user); // to create class for that

          //that.profileData.setProfile(that.uid,that.name,that.photo);
          //console.log("id:"+this.uid+this.name+this.photo);
        }, (error)=> {
          alert(error);
        })
      }
      else {
        alert('Not Logged in');
      }
    })
    /*this.photo=firebase.database().ref('users/'+this.currentUser+'/photos').on('value',snapshot=>{
      var that=this;
      that.photonew=snapshot.val().id;
    })
*/

  }


  }
  logOutFacebook(){
    Facebook.logout().then((response)=>
    {
      this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
      alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    },(error)=>{
      alert(error);
    })
  }

  //notes functions
  getNotesList(){
    console.log("get event");
    var that=this;
    this.notesData.getNotesLIst().on('value', snapshot => {
      let notesList= [];
      snapshot.forEach( snap => {
        console.log("id note"+snap.val().id);
        notesList.push({
          id: snap.val().id,
          title: snap.val().title,
          desc: snap.val().desc,
          color:snap.val().color,
        });
      });
      that.notes = notesList;
    });
  }
  addNotes() {
    let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
      //title: 'הכנס פתק',
      cssClass:'noteAlert',
      message: "הכנס פתק תיאור",
      inputs: [
        {
          name: 'title',
          placeholder: 'כותרת'
        },
        {
          name: 'desc',
          placeholder: 'פרטים'
        },
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'ביטול',
          handler: data => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'הוסף',
          handler: data => {
           this.data.title=data.title;
            this.data.desc=data.desc;
            //this.notesData.createNote(this.data.title, this.data.desc);
            console.log('פתק נשמר');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    prompt.present();

   console.log(this.data.title, this.data.desc);

  }
  addNote(){
    this.navCtrl.push(AddNote);
  }

  delete(id:number){
  }
  update(id:number){}
}
```

Comment: what plugin ???

Comment: @e666 i use cordova plugin

Comment: which one exactly ? there are plenty of it. We cannot help you if we don't have all the info. Also, could you provide code (by editing your post) ?

Comment: yes i install it ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"

Comment: i edited my post and add all my facebook code.

Comment: Can you add the code where you call logout ? The error seems like logout is called before you login.

Comment: sure, i added it.